# How to get preceding sibling count for this xml tag attribute value?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to get the count of ProcessId which is having value 1234.Current foucus element is PlayBack

```
<WorkFlow>
<Step>
<PlayBack>
<AppInfo ProcessId="1234"/>
</PlayBack>
</Step>
<Step>
<PlayBack>
<AppInfo ProcessId="1234"/>
</PlayBack>
</Step>
<Step>
<PlayBack>
<AppInfo ProcessId="1284"/>
</PlayBack>
</Step>
</WorkFlow>
```

I tried this code but don't know where i am doing wrong

```
Here $ActivePID=1234 and $AppVaribale is some value i need to print if the ProcessID is unique
 <xsl:if test="((count(preceding-sibling::Step/PlayBack/AppInfo[@ProcessID= $ActivePID])= 0) and (GeneralInfo/@AdaptorID = 1))">
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select ="$AppVaribale"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are indeed positioned on a `PlayBack` element, the expression you need is this

```
<xsl:if test="count(../preceding-sibling::Step/PlayBack/AppInfo[@ProcessId = $ActivePID]) = 0">
```

Note the use of `..` to get the parent `Step` element, as `PlayBack` itself does not have any siblings. Also note your current expression referred to `ProcessID` not `ProcessId` (XML is case-sensitive)

However, this is not actually the most efficient approach. Perhaps you need to read up on a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), which can be used to find the first occurrence of each value.

You would define a key like so

```
<xsl:key name="Processes" match="PlayBack" use="AppInfo/@ProcessId" />
```

Then your expression is written like this

```
<xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('Processes', $ActivePID)[1])">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="Processes" match="PlayBack" use="AppInfo/@ProcessId" />
    <xsl:template match="PlayBack">
        <xsl:variable name="ActivePID" select="AppInfo/@ProcessId" />
        <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('Processes', $ActivePID)[1])">
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select ="'Test'"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that if you actually wanted to find elements that only occurred once (rather than the first occurrence of each element) you can change the expression to this:

```
<xsl:if test="count(key('Processes', $ActivePID)[1]) = 1">
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jak,

USe below XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name = "Count" >
<xsl:value-of select = "count(WorkFlow/Step/PlayBack/AppInfo[@ProcessId =  1234])"/>
</xsl:variable>
<test>
<xsl:value-of select ="$Count"/>
</test>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Just to make sure , its working .. am adding the count value variable i.e, Count in between Test tag.

Comment: along with your solution i tried this one also and both worked fine                                                              <xsl:if test="count(../preceding-sibling::Step/PlayBack/AppInfo[@ProcessId = $ActivePID]) = 0">

Comment: thanx for the alternative solution

Answer (score 1):

You say the "current focus element is PlayBack", but that element doesn't have any preceding siblings named Step (in fact it doesn't have any preceding sibling elements at all). You are missing a `..`

```
count(../preceding-sibling::Step/PlayBack/AppInfo[@ProcessID=$ActivePID])
```